# How can I send the key ENTER to the page setup dialog in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, shell, wsh

I have the following code that changes the page orientation. it works in IE6 but not in IE7. it gets as far as %a and does not send the enter or tab keys so that i can hit 'OK'

```
var shell;
function SetPrintProperties() {

shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.SendKeys("%fu"); // %=alt  f= file u= page setup
window.setTimeout("javascript:SetPaperSize();", 1500);

}

function SetPaperSize() {

shell.sendKeys("%a{ENTER}");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this

```
shell.SendKeys("%~");
```

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)